# StaticInjectorError when importing a custom-made Angular library

Tags: html, angular, dependency-injection, angular7, angular-library

I've built my own Angular library (called ProcessorModule) and want to use it in other applications. Whenever I import the library however, I get the following error:

```
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[StatusComponent -> MainProcessComponent].
NullInjectorError: No provider for MainProcessComponent!
```

This occurs within the html of MainProcessComponent which has a nested StatusComponent (specifically when I use the 'status' selector:

```
/* MainProcessComponent.html */
<h2>This is the MainProcessComponent view</h2>

<div>
    <status></status>
</div>
```

This is my processor.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { MainProcessComponent } from "./components/process.component";
import { StatusComponent } from "./components/status.component";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    routing,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MainProcessComponent,
    ProcessComponent,
    StatusComponent
  ],
  declarations: [
    MainProcessComponent,
    ProcessComponent,
    StatusComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [

  ]
})
export class ProcessorModule { }
```

I build/pack a .tgz file for ProcessorModule and import it into my outside application using

```
import { ProcessorModule} from "processor-module";
```

Within the imports section of `@NgModule` I add:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...,
        ProcessorModule,
        ...
    ]
})
export class OutsideAppModule { }
```

Keep in mind the above code has been simplified to help illustrate my issue. I thought adding both components to the exports section of `processor.module.ts` would have solved my problem. Can anyone see what exactly I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I've added MainProcessComponent to both the 'exports' and 'declarations' section of processor.module.ts but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

`MainProcessComponent` is not exported in `processor.module.ts`'s exports array.

**processor.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [..],
  exports: [
    ProcessComponent,
    StatusComponent,
    MainProcessComponent // added
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  bootstrap: [... ]
})
export class ProcessorModule { }
```

Comment: I added MainProcessComponent to both the 'exports' and 'declarations' sections but I still get the same error.

Comment: When does the error occur while serving the app  or building?

Comment: While serving. My outside app runs, I click a button that brings up the MainProcessComponent view (with the 'status' selector), and then I get the error.

Comment: Try reserve the app.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem - I had some components declared in the constructor of another component (not shown above) that were unused. After removing them everything worked fine.